# Multiple Nested Joins in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, nested

I have a fairly simple database for a European style School system. A School can have multiple classes, Teachers can have assigned one or more classes from any School. Each student can have assigned a single class, and can have multiple grades from each teacher assigned to the class.

The checks for weather or not the teacher is assigned to the student class is done inside the software itself.

Here is the database diagram:

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg6My.png)

I have to do get back the following reports using SQL:

- Report Grades by Class: Select a class and have a table with every students grades, their average and the teacher who assigned the grade. (Table Sturcture: Teacher, Student, Grade_01, Grade_02, Grade_03, Grade_04, Average Grade)
- Report Average Teacher Grade by School: Display a table with the teacher name, his class, and the average grade for the entire class. (Table Structure: Teacher, Class, Average Grade)

I managed to do the first "Report Grades by Class" Table by using the following SQL Code:

```
SELECT grades.grade_id, teachers.teacher_name, students.student_name, grades.grade_01, grades.grade_02, grades.grade_03, grades.grade_04 
FROM grades 
JOIN teachers 
ON teachers.teacher_id = grades.teacher_id 
JOIN students 
ON students.student_id = grades.student_id 
WHERE students.class_id = ?
```

But I don't know how to go about generating the second report, I have tried countless times...

So, how do I display a table with the teacher name, his class, and the average grade for the entire class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Format your code properly.  It's hard to read if it's all in one line.

Comment: "and the average grade for the entire class" - Which one? grade_01, grade_02, ... ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks Eric, Formated. The average for all the 4 grades, AVG(grade_01) and the other 3.

Comment: Join all involved tables and group by class and teacher.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul. Do you think you could help me with the SQL code? I've tried to join all the tables but i get a lot of errors.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried and the errors.

Comment: Just did, the code i posted as an answer is the closest one i got working, buy it gives me the average by teacher and not by class.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
teacher_name as 'Teacher', 
class_name as 'Class', 
avg(grade_01 + grade_02 + grade_03 + grade_04) as 'Average Grade' from teachers 
join class_teacher on teachers.teacher_id = class_teacher.teacher_id
join clases on clases.class_id = class_teacher.class_id
join grades on grades.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id
group by teacher_name, class_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The I tested the code but it gives me the same average for every class, so it's giving me the teacher average instead of the class average.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer AnumR

I have modified the code you provided to make it so you can select the teachers and classes by the school ID.

But the code outputs the average by teacher and not by class.

```
SELECT teacher_name AS 'Teacher', class_name AS 'Class', 
AVG(grade_01 + grade_02 + grade_03 + grade_04)/4 AS 'Average Grade' FROM teachers 
JOIN class_teacher ON teachers.teacher_id = class_teacher.teacher_id
JOIN clases ON clases.class_id = class_teacher.class_id
JOIN grades ON grades.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id
WHERE clases.school_id = 2
GROUP BY teacher_name, class_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem here (and one I suspect you're reluctant to address) is one of poor design.

While by no means a definitive solution, a valid design might be as follows:

```
Teacher, Student, Grade, Score
```

Average grade would then be something calculated on the fly.